# insert into sql unknown field

Tags: java, mysql, sql, insert-into

i'm using java with eclipse and mysql for database.I have a class for connecting to database and write to variables to database.Here is that class:

```
package model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class AddChannelDb {
    public void AddToDb(String channelName, int channelNo)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String db = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/digiturkschema";
    Class.forName(myDriver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db, "root",
            "****");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO channelstable(channelNo,channelName) VALUES ("+ channelNo + "," + channelName + ")");
}
}
```

These two variables (channelName and channelNo) are entered by user in my view class and comes here from a get method for a textfield.I am getting these variables without a problem, i controled it but somehow i cant write to my database.For example when i enter "showTv" for channelName and "21" for channelNo,i get an error like:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'showTv' in 'field list'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1816)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1730)
at model.AddChannelDb.AddToDb(AddChannelDb.java:18)
at controller.DigiTurkController$addChannelBtnListener.actionPerformed(DigiTurkController.java:47)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I searched web really hard but i couldnt find anything.It looks like a simple problem but i cant fix it.Thanks for your time and help.(Btw i am sure that table name and variable names are correct.)

Comment: In response to [converting-java-to-exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586227/converting-java-to-exe):You either need to install a local database on all clients or host your database online (mysql hosting etc.). Other options are using embedded databases that kind of come bundled within the app like SQLite, Apache Derby etc.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
 st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO channelstable(channelNo,channelName) VALUES ("+ channelNo + "," + channelName + ")");
```

To:

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO channelstable(channelNo,channelName) VALUES (\'"+ channelNo + "\',\'" + channelName + "\')");
```

Basically you are missing quotes around your values that you want to insert.

Note aside: I would suggest you use [preparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) where you wont have to take care of quotes and your SQL will be safe and not vulnerable to SQL injection as it is now in its current form.

Comment: thanks,it solved the problem and i am looking for preparedStatement now.Good advice,thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `conn.createStatement()`, instead use `con.prepareStatement()`, it will protect you from SQLInjection.

Your code will look like this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO channelstable(channelNo,channelName) VALUES ( ? , ? )";
Statement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

st.setInt(1, channelNo);    
st.setString(2, channelName);
st.executeUpdate(sql);
```